# Oracle string_agg(distinct columnname) does not work in pl/sql, only in sqldeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I am trying to get the string_agg function, [detailed here](http://www.oracle-base.com/dba/miscellaneous/string_agg.sql) to work with the distinct keyword.  Sample usage:

```
select string_agg(distinct a.name), a.id from tbl_a a group by a.id
```

The problem is that this works in sqldeveloper, but when running it in application express in an anonymous pl/sql block, it refuses to accept the distinct keyword and I get an error saying that the distinct is not allowed.  Why would it be doing this?  Is there a simple workaround?  I am using 10.2 and application express 3.2

Edit: to clarify, I am interested in solving this problem, but if there is another string_agg/group_concat function that I can use I am open to any ideas.

Edit: I eventually want to be able to do something like

```
select string_agg(distinct a.name),string_agg(distinct a.city), a.id from tbl_a a group by a.id
```

and have both string_agg columns be deduped... this is a problem when using a distinct in a subquery as it does not get the distinct values for both columns...

Answer (score 2):

```
-- Subject: string_agg + distinct/unique

-- Function string_agg creates a comma separated list of cursor values
-- Source : http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php

-- This function has been renamed to string_agg_unique and modified to return a unique list of values (unsort) 
-- (The merge part has not been modified/supported)


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_string_agg_unique AS OBJECT
(
  g_string  VARCHAR2(32767),

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx  IN OUT  t_string_agg_unique)
    RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self   IN OUT  t_string_agg_unique,
                                       value  IN      VARCHAR2 )
     RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self         IN   t_string_agg_unique,
                                         returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
                                         flags        IN   NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self  IN OUT  t_string_agg_unique,
                                     ctx2  IN      t_string_agg_unique)
    RETURN NUMBER
);
/
SHOW ERRORS


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_string_agg_unique IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx  IN OUT  t_string_agg_unique)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    sctx := t_string_agg_unique(NULL);
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self   IN OUT  t_string_agg_unique,
                                       value  IN      VARCHAR2 )
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    -- Concatenate string only when not already existing in the list (=unique)
    IF instr ( SELF.g_string||','      ,       ','||value||',' ) = 0 
    THEN
       SELF.g_string := self.g_string || ',' || value;
    END IF  ; 
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self         IN   t_string_agg_unique,
                                         returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
                                         flags        IN   NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := RTRIM(LTRIM(SELF.g_string, ','), ',');
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self  IN OUT  t_string_agg_unique,
                                     ctx2  IN      t_string_agg_unique)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.g_string := SELF.g_string || ',' || ctx2.g_string;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;


END;
/
SHOW ERRORS



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_agg_unique (p_input VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING t_string_agg_unique;
/
SHOW ERRORS


  -- example
  select string_agg_unique ( fruit ) fruit_list from (
     select * from ( 
        select 'Apple' fruit from dual
        union all
        select 'Cherries' fruit from dual  
        union all
        select 'Apple' fruit from dual  
        union all
        select 'Lemon' fruit from dual  
     )
  ) ;
```

### FRUIT_LIST

Apple,Cherries,Lemon

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour seems to be a bug according to the last post in this [AskTom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:15637744429336#1988197700346083006).

Moving the distinct operation into a sub query should work:

```
select   string_agg(sq.name)
        ,sq.id 
from     (
         select distinct 
                a.name
               ,a.id 
         from   tbl_a a 
         ) sq
group by sq.id
```

Comment: this would work for string_agg on a single column... but if I want to do multiple columns I have to do multiple subqueries.

Comment: true. Another advice in that thread is to use dynamic sql. That approach would allow you to use the exact same statement, which you can use outside a pl/sql block. You could take a look at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#i13130 to get started.